# Is there any difference between ({}) and {} in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
let obj1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
};
let obj2 = ({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
});
```

Are `obj1` and `obj2` totally the same? Are they the same way to define an object in javascript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are `obj1` and `obj2` totally the same?

Yes. While they are not *strictly equal* in your question (they are not the same object references), they are essentially identical.

> Is there any difference between `({})` and `{}` in javascript?

**Yes.** I know two situations off the top of my mind where this could make a difference.

---

First, you might have encountered this syntax in [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) before:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let mappedArray = array.map(value => ({
    original: value,
    double: value * 2
}));
```

In here it *does* make a difference, as curly brackets by themselves would be interpreted as the boundaries of the function passed as the argument of `map`. That is, without the extra brackets, you would need:

```
array.map(value => {
    return {
        original: value,
        double: value * 2
    };
});
```

As a side-note, both of the above are identical to the following (except for the handling of `this`, which is not hindered by ES6 arrow syntax):

```
array.map(function (value) {
    return {
        original: value,
        double: value * 2
    };
});
```

---

Second, an *object literal expression* by itself is invalid in JavaScript, because the curly brackets are interpreted as the opening and closing brackets of a *block*.

So while this is a syntax error:

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
}
```

... the following is not (although it's absolutely useless by itself):

```
({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is **no**. There is no difference. You can omit the brackets and get the exact same result.

Answer (score 1):

They are totally the same , in fact you can omit the () in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

In your example they are exactly the same. Parenthesis are useless to declare `obj2` in this case.

Parenthesis in programming (when evaluating a value) act like in equations, so having:

```
let obj1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
};
let obj2 = ({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
});
```

Is the same as:

```
x = 2
x = (2)
```

in mathematics